# SoundFont Player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, naudio

I am currently trying to copy sample data in a soundfont to an AudioClip in unity. I am using the `AudioClip.SetData()`.

`public bool SetData(float[] data, int offsetSamples);`

The problem is the `NAudio.SoundFont.SampleData` returns a `byte` value. So I need to convert that `byte` value to a `float[]`.

I've tried normalizing the byte value and adding it to the float array, but there is no sound coming out from the audio source. i appreciate any assistance/advice on how to solve this challenge. Thank you in advance

```
// Copy the sample data to the AudioClip
byte sampleData = soundfont.SampleData[sampleIndex];

// Convert byte to float and Normalize byte value to float range (0 to 1)
float floatData = sampleData / 255f; 
audioClip.SetData(new float[] { floatData }, 0);

// Set the audioSource.clip and play the AudioClip
audioSource.clip = audioClip;
audioSource.pitch = 3;
audioSource.Play();
return;
```